# Can we access node/host process from the Kubernetes pod?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, elastic-stack, elastic-beats

Is there a way to access the underlying host/node's process from Kubernetes pod in the same way like we access the host/node's filesystem by using `hostPath` volume mount?

PS: I am trying to monitor the node process with the help of `auditbeat` deployed as a pod on Kubernetes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is [`hostPID: true` in the PodSpec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#podspec-v1-core):

```yaml
spec:
  hostPID: true
  containers:
  - name: show-init
    command:
    - ps
    - -p
    - "1"
```

should, in theory, output "/sbin/init" since it is running in the host's PID namespace